# facebook like iframe with old browsers

Tags: css, iframe, browser, facebook-like

if I load this web site
http://liberainformazione.it/
with old or new browsers, my facebook like iframe button are visualized in two different ways.

[image]

How can I render correctly this iframe indipendently from browsers?
This is the web site:
http://liberainformazione.it/

Thanks a lot.

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/116754/best-css-reset)

Comment: Did you use the advice in the answers? Say normalize.css or any of the other libraries mentioned?

Comment: I use Eric Meyer's CSS reset

Comment: I suggest that you try some of the others, I am sure that one of them would help.